# Spring batch can multiple steps be exceuted in prallel in different JVMs

Tags: java, spring-batch

Spring batch - Need help to run independent steps of a batch job in parallel and in multiple nodes. A spring batch job(JobA) with three steps [StepA(in compute1) and StepB (in compute2) and StepC]

StepA and StepB are independent steps and memory intensive and hence cannot be run on same compute node/JVM in parallel. For StepC to start both(StepA and StepB) needs to be completed successfully. I do not want to execute StepA and StepB in sequence to save time. In order to achieve parallelism StepA and StepB wants to be run in parallel on different nodes.

I understand remote chunking and partitioning helps to split the dataset and run the same step by using multiple worker nodes.

Comment: I am not fully understand why you want to use that steps in different JVM. Not sure but maybe asynchronous calls can help. I.e. `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

Comment: due to compute limitation and steps are memory intensive operations, i cannot run both the steps in parallel on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

No, not out-of-the-box. You might need a custom `StepHandler` that is able to run a step remotely and return its step execution to the enclosing job.

Comment: Thanks @mahmoud-ben-hassine is this something which we can see in future Spring Batch increments?

Comment: No, there is no plan to support that for now.